# How does JRE know the line number of code where exception occured?

Tags: java

Consider the following Exception print

```
java.util.NoSuchElementException
    at java.util.StringTokenizer.nextToken(StringTokenizer.java:332)
    at com.infoaxe.mr.homefeed.ReduceTwo.reduce(MapReduce.java:290)
```

Since Java is a compiled language and what runs in JVM is the bytecode and not the source code itself how does the exception know on which line it occurred ? Example line 332 in above case ?

Comment: The bytecode probably includes [Debug Symbols](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debug_symbol)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Simply because the compiler includes the line numbers in the generated byte-code. There are `-g` [options](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javac.html#options) (in the Oracle javac compiler) allowing to turn that off, if you want to.